# Angular suddenly stopped working in dev, prod and local with no change, compiles successfully

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, typeerror

> TypeError: n is not iterable TypeError: n is not iterable

I have an Angular and nodejs project running on heroku. The application was working fine and now all of a sudden I am having Angular building successfully, but get an error once I load the app. The error is minimal and I couldn't find anything online. Any help would be appreciated.

> core.js:6210 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: n is not iterable
> TypeError: n is not iterable
>
> at qe (router.js:3414:30)
> at Xe.processChildren (router.js:3293:32)
> at Xe.processSegmentGroup (router.js:3263:25)
> at Xe.recognize (router.js:3242:31)
> at router.js:3216:14
> at l.project (router.js:3213:1)
> at l._tryNext (mergeMap.js:44:27)
> at l._next (mergeMap.js:34:18)
> at l.next (Subscriber.js:49:18)
> at l._next (tap.js:46:26)
> at T (zone-evergreen.js:798:39)
> at T (zone-evergreen.js:750:21)
> at zone-evergreen.js:860:21
> at u.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399:35)
> at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28567:33)
> at u.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398:40)
> at s.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167:51)
> at y (zone-evergreen.js:569:39)
> at j (polyfill.min.js:6:49500)
> at u (polyfill.min.js:6:48005)

The error I get when running it locally is:

```
core.js:6210 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: mergedNodes is not iterable
TypeError: mergedNodes is not iterable
    at mergeEmptyPathMatches (router.js:3414:1)
    at Recognizer.processChildren (router.js:3293:1)
    at Recognizer.processSegmentGroup (router.js:3263:1)
    at Recognizer.recognize (router.js:3242:1)
    at recognize (router.js:3216:1)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.project (router.js:3463:20)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:44:1)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:34:1)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49:1)
    at TapSubscriber._next (tap.js:46:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:750:1)
    at zone-evergreen.js:860:1
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28567:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398:1)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167:1)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:569:1)
    at j (polyfill.min.js:6:49500)
    at u (polyfill.min.js:6:48005)
```

and

```
Uncaught TypeError: 100,200,201,300,301,302 is not iterable!
    at push.SlkY.module.exports (_for-of.js:14:1)
    at _collection.js:61:1
    at new Set (es6.set.js:8:26)
    at 8Y7J (core.js:152:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:85:30)
    at Object.zUnb (main.ts:1:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:85:30)
    at 0 (alert.component.ts:12:28)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:85:30)
    at checkDeferredModules (runtime.js:46:23)
```

and

```
 Uncaught TypeError: true,1 is not iterable!
    at SlkY.t.exports (_for-of.js:14:42)
    at _collection.js:61:36
    at new <anonymous> (es6.set.js:8:34)
    at Object.fDlF (browser.js:613:29)
    at c (runtime-es2015.efcb1777b316fde67ca4.js:1:552)
    at Object.omvX (animations.js:1:1)
    at c (runtime-es2015.efcb1777b316fde67ca4.js:1:552)
    at 1Xc+ (overlay.js:2956:7)
    at c (runtime-es2015.efcb1777b316fde67ca4.js:1:552)
    at Object.nmIE (subscribeToArray.js:5:16)
SlkY.t.exports @ _for-of.js:14
(anonymous) @ _collection.js:61
(anonymous) @ es6.set.js:8
fDlF @ browser.js:613
c @ runtime-es2015.efcb1777b316fde67ca4.js:1
omvX @ animations.js:1
c @ runtime-es2015.efcb1777b316fde67ca4.js:1
1Xc+ @ overlay.js:2956
c @ runtime-es2015.efcb1777b316fde67ca4.js:1
nmIE @ subscribeToArray.js:5
c @ runtime-es2015.efcb1777b316fde67ca4.js:1
zUnb @ app.component.ts:60
c @ runtime-es2015.efcb1777b316fde67ca4.js:1
0 @ ssr-window.esm.js:147
c @ runtime-es2015.efcb1777b316fde67ca4.js:1
t @ runtime-es2015.efcb1777b316fde67ca4.js:1
r @ runtime-es2015.efcb1777b316fde67ca4.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-es2015.938f4aeb39839be1485f.js:1
```

the issue might be in core-js:

my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "main": "server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build DineNGo --aot --configuration=${ENV}",
    "preinstall": "npm install --location=global @angular/cli @angular/compiler-cli --legacy-peer-deps",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "cypress:open": "cypress open",
    "swagger": "node ./swagger.js",
    "cypress:run": "cypress run",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1102.19",
    "@angular/animations": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.2.19",
    "@angular/common": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^11.0.0-beta.33",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/material": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/router": "^11.0.6",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "9.0.2",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^11.2.19",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.7.42",
    "@types/chartist": "^0.9.38",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^3.1.47",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.22",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.135",
    "@types/node": "^11.15.54",
    "@types/socket.io": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "@types/w3c-web-usb": "^1.0.10",
    "@types/web-bluetooth": "0.0.4",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^11.1.0",
    "angular-cc-library": "^2.1.2",
    "angular-cli-ghpages": "^0.6.2",
    "angular-notifier": "^9.1.0",
    "angular-responsive-carousel": "^2.0.2",
    "angularx-qrcode": "^11.0.0",
    "apexcharts": "^3.44.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "chartist": "^0.11.4",
    "clover-ecomm-sdk": "^1.0.0",
    "config": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "2.5.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "exec": "^0.2.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-jwt": "^8.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fontawesome": "^5.6.3",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "got": "^11.8.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lz-string": "^1.5.0",
    "material-dashboard": "^2.1.0",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "material-design-lite": "^1.3.0",
    "mdbootstrap": "^4.19.2",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.0.10",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.15",
    "mongoose-to-swagger": "^1.5.1",
    "ng-apexcharts": "1.5.12",
    "ng-chartist": "^4.1.0",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.14",
    "ng-socket-io": "^0.2.4",
    "ngx-autosize": "^1.8.4",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-guided-tour": "^1.1.11",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^10.0.0",
    "ngx-swiper-wrapper": "^10.0.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "11.1.1",
    "openai": "^4.17.4",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.4",
    "resize-base64": "^1.0.12",
    "rootpath": "^0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "socket.io": "^4.6.2",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.6.2",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^5.0.0",
    "time-ago-pipe": "^1.3.2",
    "ts-node": "6.0.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "typescript": "4.1.6",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^11.0.6",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "cypress": "^13.5.0",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1",
    "cypress-multi-reporters": "^1.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.10.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ng2-charts-schematics": "^0.1.7",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "swagger-autogen": "^2.23.7",
    "swiper": "^6.8.4",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.18.2",
    "npm": "9.8.1"
  }
}
```

My package.lock file can be found here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19xsXokxPTcu5TV7wRX3BGriFZkRii2e1/view?usp=sharing

There seems to be a package updated recently or Angular libraries that is causing this issue because even if I revert back to working builds, it still doesn't work.

only place I see mergenodes which is the error is:
[image]

[Video Of Issue](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EVK-4TuWO-C98P1Ut7rdmG5hd729_arQ/view?usp=drive_link)

Comment: May be you need to delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` then try to install all of packages again using `npm i -f`

Comment: I tried that but no luck. It was working fine then stopped working without any change since 9pm ish yesterday. Havent been able to get it working locally, in dev or production since.

Comment: Make sure backend doesn't return some incorrect value (such as object). The first exception seems to be in the [router](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/router/src/recognize.ts#L539), is url correct?

Comment: What node version do you use?

Comment: Node version 18.18.2

Comment: do u have and use package-lock ?

Comment: @PetrAveryanov I added a link to the package-lock file.

Comment: @z123 u have it but do u really use it during build?

Comment: @PetrAveryanov what do you mean? It is generated each build and I think it is used, how can I check?

Comment: upon debugging the main.ts, I noticed the error is coming from platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed this from index.html to get it working:  `<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js"></script>`